# How to decide on the standard error for difference of standard deviations

Tags: statistics, sampling, sampling-theory

[image]

In this problem the null hypothesis is that $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$ then why in the standard error a common sigma value is not used? It can he found as $\sigma = ({n_{1}s_1^{2}+ n_{2}s_{2}^2})/({n_{1}+n_{2}})$
And also while testing for difference of sample means i.e $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$, does it always mean that $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$? Or does that happen only when the samples are drawn from the same population? Basically what’s the difference from the null hypothesis that $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$ and the case when samples are drawn from same population? **Is the testing done for the significant difference of population mean or sample mean?** also in difference of proportions, under the hypothesis $P_1=P_1$ the standard error also has one term $P_1=P_2=P$ why doesn’t that happen here for sigma? Or let me put it this way, under the null hypothesis $P_1=P_1$ the standard error also has one term $H_0: P_1=P_2=P$ Is this $P$ same as the one calculated from $P=(n_1p_1+n_2p_2)/(n_1+n_2)$ where $p_i$ is the sample proportion.  [image]

EDIT: I referred another text and here it says, under null hypothesis $H_0: \sigma_1=\sigma_2$ and continues to say that, i.e sample standard deviations don’t differ significantly. But are not $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ population standard deviations?

Comment: As @heropup has explained, both screen shots contain errors. Nothing can be rescued from this. The statistics labeled `z` in the screen shots have no relationship to normal distributions. "Complete garbage" is a very restrained and civilized characterization.

Answer (score 1):

The provided solution is complete garbage.  Disregard it **entirely**.  The test statistic they use is not normally distributed under the assumption of the null hypothesis.  I don't know where this text comes from, but such an elementary mistake discredits the whole text.

To test the equality of variances (and in turn, standard deviations), the usual test is the [$F$-ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances) for normally distributed populations, and [Levene's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test) when departure from normality is considered.  But under **no** circumstances does that solution make any sense whatsoever.  It looks like the author of the solution simply treated the sample standard deviations like sample means, and assumed something like [Welch's $t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test) would be an appropriate test statistic.  But even then, there are mistakes:  first, $z$ is not appropriate because the true population standard deviation is unknown.  Second, there's an extra factor of $2$ in the denominators.  Third, there is a sign error in the last expression where the author uses $-$ instead of $+$.  But this is all irrelevant because as I have already stated, the solution is garbage.

Comment: I referred another text and I’ve included that also. Under the null hypothesis $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ why in the standard error they don’t put $\sigma$ for both and take it common? They do that for difference of means when the sample is drawn from same population.

Comment: @danny I would not even consider using such a test.  The presumption (which is not necessarily true) is that when the sample size is sufficiently large, the difference of sample standard deviations $s_1 - s_2$ under the null hypothesis is approximately normal with mean $0$ and standard deviation equal to the standard error of that difference.  That said, your question stems from a false premise:  you don't know what the true standard deviation for both samples actually is!

Comment: @danny A test for the difference of means will either use a pooled estimate of the standard deviation, or if the population standard deviation is given, then that is what is used.  But you are not given a population standard deviation.  You only have two estimates from different samples.

Comment: Yes that assumption is made in the text that things are approximately normal. Granted that (however wrong) I’m now more confused. Why can’t we do the pooled estimate of standard deviation here from sample standard deviation like in the case of difference of mean? Null hypothesis says that $sigma_1=\sigma_2$ right why can’t we take it to be some $\sigma$ and find that value as a pooled estimate from dampen standard deviations as in the case of difference of mean. There it is done. Why not here? I guess I’m confusing something.

Comment: @danny I keep repeating myself:  that assumption is **not** necessarily true, even for a large sample size, which is why I keep saying that the test is not to be used.  You also do not seem to understand the difference between a parameter and an estimator for that parameter.  $\sigma$ is not the same as $s$.  Under the null, $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$, but what is that value?  You don't know it and if you did, you wouldn't need to do the test in the first place.  Moreover, what you actually need here is the standard error of the difference $s_1 - s_2$.  That is not $\sigma$.

Comment: I have no more information or guidance for you.  If you still don't understand, you need to use a different statistics textbook.

Comment: I’m really sorry for taking your time. I see the difference between the parameter and the estimate. I guess I’m not putting my confusion clear. Let me put it one last time, in the second picture I posted, the same s.e in the denominator is used except the value 2 for difference of mean. There under the assumption that the samples are drawn from same population they assume $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma$ and if $\sigma$ isn’t given they calculate that using sample values as per the formula for $\sigma$ I’ve posted in my main question. Why it can’t be done here? I’m really sorry.

Comment: Standard error for difference of sample means also has the values $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. There in the formula they take $\sigma$ out common and find the value as the polled estimate using $n_i$ and $s_i$. What I’m not getting is why can’t I do it here for difference of standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question appears to be that a "common sigma value" *was in fact* used in  the *original* definition of the $\ z\ $ statistic, given as
$$
z=\frac{s_1-s_2}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n_1}+\frac{1}{2n_2}}}\ ,
$$
on [page $20$](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=NlnzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q&f=false) of *Statistics for Engineers*, in which the problem described under Example $2$ of your first illustration appears as Problem $6$ on [page $24$](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=NlnzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false).  However, when you replace $\ \sigma\ $ with its *estimate* $\ \sqrt{\frac{n_1s_1^2+n_2s_2^2}{n_1+n_2}}\ $ you get the following *estimate* $\ z_e\ $ for the value of $\ z\ $:
\begin{align}
z_e&=\frac{s_1-s_2}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{n_1s_1^2+n_2s_2^2}{n_1+n_2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2n_1}+\frac{1}{2n_2}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{s_1-s_2}{\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{2n_2}+\frac{s_2^2}{2n_1}}}
\end{align}
Please note the following:

- In your question, you've omitted the square root sign from $\ \sqrt{\frac{n_1s_1^2+n_2s_2^2}{n_1+n_2}}\ $, which is a *random* quantity whose value is *only* an estimate of $\ \sigma\ $, and *not* equal to it (except by a very lucky coincidence).
- In the above expression for $\ z_e\ $  the indices on $\ s\ $ and $\ n\ $ in the fractions in the denominator
  *do not match*.  In the examples given in the above-cited book, this expression for $\ z_e\ $ gets replaced without explanation by $\ \frac{s_1-s_2}{\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{2n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{2n_2}}}\ $, which corresponds to taking $\ \sqrt{\big(n_2s_1^2+n_1s_2^2\big)\big/\big(n_1+n_2\big)}\ $ as an estimate for $\ \sigma\ $ instead of the much more natural $\ \sqrt{\big(n_1s_1^2+n_2s_2^2\big)\big/\big(n_1+n_2\big)}\ $.
- As heropup alludes to in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920582/how-to-decide-on-the-standard-error-for-difference-of-standard-deviations/3920629#3920629) (which I fully agree with), none of $\ s_1, s_2, s_1-s_2, z\ $, or either version of $\ z_e\ $, have an approximately normal distribution, *even for very large* samples from a normally distributed population—contrary to the presumptions of the above-cited book.  Thus, any calculation of significance levels based on the presumption that $\ z_e\ $ is normally distributed is completely unjustified and will almost certainly be wrong.

**Update**

If the samples are independently drawn from two homogeneous, normally distributed populations with the same variance (but possibly different means), then the true  distribution of the absolute value of the statistic $\ z\ $ defined in Example $2$ of the OP's first illustration can be expressed in terms of the [$F$-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) with $\ n_1-1\ $ and $\ n_2-1\ $ degrees of freedom.  This makes it easy to construct examples showing how the assumption that this statistic has a standard normal distribution can give completely erroneous results.

Take the case when $\ n_1=150,$ $n_2=250,$$\ s_1=14.0\ $, and $\ s_2=11.3\ $. Then
$$
z=\frac{14.0-11.3}{\sqrt{\frac{(14.0)^2}{300}+\frac{(11.3)^2}{500}}}\approx2.83\ .
$$
If $\ z\ $ had a standard normal distribution, this would give a $p$-value of
$$
P\big(|z|>2.83\big)=2{\cal N}(0,1;-2.83)\approx0.00465\ ,
$$
implying that the null hypothesis could be rejected at the $0.5\%$ level of significance.

To obtain the true distribution of $\ |z|\ $, rewrite $\ z\ $ as
$$
z=\frac{\frac{s_1}{s_2}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n_1}\left(\frac{s_1}{s_2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2n_2}}}\ .
$$
A little algebraic manipulation then shows that
\begin{align}
|z|\le x&\iff \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n_1}\right)\left(\frac{s_1}{s_2}\right)^2-2\left(\frac{s_1}{s_2}\right)+1-\frac{x^2}{2n_2}\le0\\
&\iff\ell_\ell\le \frac{s_1}{s_2}\le\ell_u\ \ \ (\text{ provided }\ \ x^2<2n_1),
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\ell_\ell&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n_2}\right)}}{1-\frac{x^2}{2n_1}}\ \ \text{ and}\\
\ell_u&=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n_2}\right)}}{1-\frac{x^2}{2n_1}}\ .
\end{align}
Under the hypotheses stated in the opening paragraph of this update, the statistic $\ \frac{n_1\big(1-n_2\big)}{n_2\big(1-n_1\big)}\left(\frac{s_1}{s_2}\right)^2\ $ has an $F$-distribution with $\ n_1-1\ $ and $\ n_2-1\ $ degrees of freedom, and so
\begin{align}
P\big(|z|\le x\big)=&\,P\left(\frac{n_1\big(1-n_2\big)\ell_\ell^2}{n_2\big(1-n_1\big)}\le\frac{n_1\big(1-n_2\big)}{n_2\big(1-n_1\big)}\left(\frac{s_1}{s_2}\right)^2\le\frac{n_1\big(1-n_2\big)\ell_u^2}{n_2\big(1-n_1\big)}\right)\\
=&\,F_{n_1-1,n_2-1}\left(\frac{n_1\big(1-n_2\big)\ell_u^2}{n_2\big(1-n_1\big)}\right)-F_{n_1-1,n_2-1}\left(\frac{n_1\big(1-n_2\big)\ell_\ell^2}{n_2\big(1-n_1\big)}\right)\ .
\end{align}
For the example immediately above $\ \frac{n_1\big(1-n_2\big)\ell_\ell^2}{n_2\big(1-n_1\big)}\ $ and $\ \frac{n_1\big(1-n_2\big)\ell_u^2}{n_2\big(1-n_1\big)}\ $ evaluate approximately to $\ 0.668\ $ and $\ 1.539\ $ respectively, giving
\begin{align}
P\big(|z|\le2.83\big)&\approx F_{149,249}\big(1.539\big)-F_{149,249}\big(0.668\big)\\
&\approx0.930\ ,
\end{align}
or $\ P\big(|z|>2.83\big)\approx0.070\ $. Thus, the true $p$-value is more than an order of magnitude larger than the erroneous value obtained by assuming $\ z\ $ has a standard normal distribution, and implies that the null hypothesis cannot be rejected even at a $5\%$ level of significance.